# Are JS developers expected to read the ECMAScript specification?

Tags: javascript, specifications, ecma

Some things, like modern assembly languages, are meant to be easily read by the computer, and not by developers.

I'm wondering if the ECMAScript specification is similar in this sense, that is, it something meant to be read only by the compiler or by someone who wants to implement said compiler. Is that the case?

Or is it not the case, and much like the users of a tool (such as React JS) are expected to read its documentation, are developers who use JavaScript expected to read the ECMAScript specification?

I don't want this question to sound opinion-based, so perhaps a slight rewording: Is the ECMAScript specification meant to be developer-readable, in general?

Comment: No, the EcmaScript specification is not meant to be machine-readable ("*read by the compiler*").

Comment: @TylerRoper I've tried before, but I could not make much sense of it. I did not know if that was because I don't enough prerequisite knowledge or experience yet to understand what it is saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody is ever *expected* to read the specification. You'd probably need to at some point or another to try to understand certain methods and their behaviors, but no - the only thing most people use is documentation, especially MDN.

The specification is only really useful if you try to understand how JavaScript is interpreted (thanks Bergi), rather than just how to use it. Up to you if you want to read it or not, but no - you're most certainly **not expected** to read the specification, or anything for that matter - sometimes, self-learning is the most effective method.

Comment: I wouldn't say "how it works". That depends a lot on the actual implementation. The spec only details the precise semantics of how code is interpreted and how builtins behave, the rules that an implementation needs to follow.